# Nothing happens on clicking any of the submit form button. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, submit-button

There is a vague thing happening.

There are 3 animated forms in 1 `html` file. In none of the form, the submit button gets clicked. By not getting clicked I mean, nothing happens when I click the submit form button. For now the action url is `#`. When the button gets clicked, the browser should change to `http://localhost:8081/twibuffer/newjsp.jsp#` but it remains the same as `http://localhost:8081/twibuffer/newjsp.jsp`.

What could be the reason for this ? I have uploaded the code at [cloud9](https://c9.io/suhailgupta03/buggy-space-1) with the preview.

*Note: Due to the code being lengthy , I didn't copy that on SO.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be that you are telling the submit button to not carry out the default action.

```
$form_wrapper.find('input[type="submit"]')
    .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

This is from line 180 of your hello-world.html file.